# Import data from Firebase to list

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I wanna import from Firebase list and sublist. Firebase Database looks something like this:

```
List_1
sublist_1 name
sublist_2 data
sublist_3 age
sublits 4 Location
List_2
sublist_1 name
sublist_2 data
sublist_3 age
sublits 4 Location
List_3
sublist_1 name
sublist_2 data
sublist_3 age
sublits 4 Location
```

This is what I have for now in Android Studio:

```
@Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mCursa);
        mListViewCurse.setAdapter(adapter);

        Firebase curseRef = mRootRef.child("List_1");
        curseRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                String message = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                Log.v("E_CHILD_ADDED", message);
                mCursa.add(message);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                String message = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                Log.v("E_CHILD_CHANGED", message);
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String message = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                Log.v("E_CHILD_REMOVED", message);
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

            }
        });

    }
```

This is the output:

- name
- data
- age
- location

Could someone please tell me what I need to add so I can see all the lists in my Android app?